# How to use RouteBoxer javascript class in asp.mvc c# code

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, google-maps-api-3, cron, routeboxer

I am facing a problem while developing asp.net mvc TRACKING application.

- I have json file of directions (which i got from google map api)
- latlngs of 10 objects

now i want to see if the latlngs are on the path or not, in simple way i can use RouteBoxer javascript class to see if latlngs are on route or not.

But i have to perform this checking after every 10 mins, so i am using Cron job for this. But i cannot run javascript from cron job.

Is there any way to do this or any alternative of RouteBoxer class in .net ? so i dont have to use javascript.

I also asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36082122/how-to-execute-javascript-from-c-sharp-in-asp-net?noredirect=1#comment59818777_36082122) but did'nt find any useful answer.

Comment: About RouteBoxer class in .net,you can refer this link(https://github.com/rustyJ4ck/RouteBoxer).

Comment: thanks.. i found this yesterday :)